# Mi login con facebook y gmail expiró o se calló, por dejar de estar en producción mi pagina web

Tags: nodejs, facebook, gmail

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tenia  en **producción** una web hecha en nodejs, que permitía logearme mediante **Facebook y Gmail**, pero estuvo **inactivo** por buen tiempo( 1 año) y ahora lo coloque nuevamente en producción pero ya no me permite tener acceso a esos servicios de *Facebook y Gmail**. Tendría que comunicarme con estos servicios para que lo activen o actualizar el código?.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][0]][0]
Login con Facebook

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendrías que ver si las apps que hiciste en fb y gmail siguen activas.

Comment: Hola @fredyfx que tal, te refieres ala parte de facebook developers en **Mis Apps**?

Comment: en efecto, ahí debes revisar, por inactividad les dan de baja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el caso de Google cuando se realiza un login, Google juega con el estandart de autenticación de oauth y bueno ahí se defini una URL de redireccion, en el popup te aparece que no está permitido la redireccion a http:/www.sportbalon.com/web/google/callback

Para solucionar eso entra a la consola de Google, al nombre del proyecto que creaste y entra a IAM, ahí te va a aparecer, 3 tipos de cuentas, revisa la parte del bloque de oauth y en específico busca el ID que coincida con el valor que pusiste en frontend para poder usar el api. Accedes a ese registro y te va a a aparecer configuración del uso de ese método de autenticación ahí tendrías que poner el dominio de la página web desde la cual vas a usar el api, al hacer eso ya no te debería aparecer como que la página web no está autorizada.